# show hidden files in speedbar

Tags: emacs

Is there a way to display what the docs call level 2 hidden files in the speedbar? E.g. **.emacs**

**Long Answer**

It turns out that the unshown files are controlled by a regular expression

Which is usually `"^\\(\\..*\\)\\'"`, which I think means everything that starts with a dot

Setting that regexp with:

```
(setq speedbar-directory-unshown-regexp "^$")
```

does the trick of showing everything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While looking at this, I discovered that there is a bug in the default value of
speedbar-directory-unshown-regexp causing the problem.  It should be redefined like this:

```
(setq speedbar-directory-unshown-regexp "^\\(CVS\\|RCS\\|SCCS\\|\\.\\.*$\\)\\'")
```

or to whatever you think makes the most sense.